# Use gutter removed from a column into witdh of another column - Susy

Tags: grid, susy-sass, gutter

See below:

[Please click here to see the image, with the question http://imgr.es/26LP](http://imgr.es/26LP)

I cant add the gutter with padding, because I'm using [Paul Irish global box sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Follows my code:

```
    $susy: (
        columns: 12,
        gutters: 18/81,
        global-box-sizing: border-box,
        debug: (
            image: show,
        ),
   );

   .container-selector-sample {
       @include container(1170px);
   }

   .column-selector-sample {
       @include span(2);
       @include breakpoint(mobile){
           @include span(12);
       }
   }

   .column-selector-sample {
       @include span(3);
       @include breakpoint(mobile){
           @include span(12);
       }
   }

   .column-selector-sample {
       @include span(7);
       @include breakpoint(mobile){
           @include span(12);
       }

   .column-selector-sample,
   .column-selector-sample {
       @include last;       
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susy has a keyword for that! See the [documentation for `narrow`, `wide`, and `wider`](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#narrow-wide-and-wider). In this case, you want to use `wide`:

```
@include span(3 wide);
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response! And for this great toolkit, Susy is awesome!

I've used the keyword "wide" previously, but something was wrong, now all is working perfectly, thank you again!